# Magento - Forgotten password link generation is using incorrect store view

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Does anybody know where I might find the functions for where a forgotten password reset link is generated in the email that is sent to the user?

For some odd reason mine is generating the reset password link with a different store view in the URL than the store view that was used to reset the password.

The link should be:

`example.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=555&token=55555555555555555`

But it is being generated as such:

`example.com/otherStoreView/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=555&token=55555555555555555`

Comment: This problem also exists in 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email template for that is:
app/locale/langcode_COUNRTYCODE/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html

And the line that generates the URL is

```
{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, open the file "app\code\local\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php".

Look for the function **sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()**. It is near the line 685.

This function looks like this:

```
    /**
 * Send email with reset password confirmation link
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
{
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    if (!$storeId) {
        $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
    }

    $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

    return $this;
}
```

In this function, Magento is getting the store id where the user was registered, but we need the store id where he made the password reset request. We just need to remove some lines and add a new one:

```
public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
{
    # this will get the current store ID
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

    $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

    return $this;
}
```

This worked for me, I hope it helps.

Comment: Upvoted for not making this change in core, but correctly moving it to /local :)